# Is there a module that creates a jquery-like bar that displays system messages at the top of the page?

Tags: 7, javascript

Is there a module that creates a jquery-like bar that displays system messages at the top of the page. (exactly like the large, red bar on this site (stack exchange)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking for recommendations or suggestions on hosting, tools, modules, themes, distributions, books, tutorials, documentation, or other off-site resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a look at the ["Purr Messages" module](http://drupal.org/project/purr_messages) - I haven't used this myself, so I don't know if it allows for the messages being displayed at the top - it says it creates a "jquery popup," which I suppose means an absolutely positioned div which either fades out or you can click away with your mouse.

I did something similar to this this on one site by simply editing `page.tpl.php` - but it sounds like you want a module, & not coding advice.

Comment: agreed and agreed. in order to get it 100% like the stack exchange bar you would have to customize the css but its a step in the right direction.

Comment: indeed ... depending on the template, may even need to muck around in the HTML if you want to get the whole body to shift downward in the super-swanky style of SE.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out the [Absolute Messages](https://www.drupal.org/project/absolute_messages) module. I have used it many times. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> Displays system messages in fully themeable colored horizontal bars on top of the page, similar to Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange network notifications.
>
> Features:
>
> - when messages are displayed content is pushed down respectively, so that nothing is covered and everything could be still interacted with,
> - alternatively, messages could be fixed to the top of the browser's viewport, so they will always remain visible regardless of scrolling,
> - each message has its own "Dismiss" (close) icon,
> - optional "Dismiss all" icon is displayed if total number of messages exceeds value defined in module settings,
> - messages could be dismissed automatically after a specific time - configurable in module settings for each message type separately,
> - hovering mouse cursor over messages resets dismiss timer,
> - provides option to re-show all already dismissed messages,
> - provides option to display only first n lines of each message, with remaining part shown after clicking on the message,
> - provides separate permissions to administer and to access Absolute messages,
> - full control over output with template files,
> - uses standard jQuery library without other modules or plugins dependencies,
> - falls back to standard Drupal's way of displaying messages when JS is not available (or when user does not have access absolute messages permission granted),
> - provides option to skip "has_js" cookie checking, which disables fallback to standard Drupal messages if no JS has been detected (for example in case of Pressflow, which dropped "has_js" cookie completely),
> - displays devel messages as standard Drupal messages.